# JPA 2.1 @ForeignKey in inheritance class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I'm migrating to JPA 2.1 and I would like to replace `@org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey` to something in inheritance class.

In fields, ok:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "any_columm_field_id",
     foreignKey = @javax.persistence.ForeignKey(name = "any_name_field_fk"))
```

**But in inheritance class, how to do it?**

Example code:

Super class

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "ANY_SUPER_TABLE_NAME")
public abstract class AnySuperClass { }
```

Specific class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANY_SPECIFIC_TABLE_NAME")
// TODO Replace to JPA 2.1
// @org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey(name = "any_specific_any_super_fk")
public class AnySpecificClass extends AnySuperClass { }
```

Any help?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: How exactly are the `ANY_SUPER_TABLE_NAME` and `ANY_SPECIFIC_TABLE_NAME` related? What field(s) join the two? Can you expand your code examples to show more detail?

Comment: Hi DuncanKinnear, Both has "ID" field and when I create a inheritance "JOINED" will cause a foreing key constraint "fk_hash" in the table "ANY_SPECIFIC_TABLE_NAME" referencing the "ID" from "ANY_SUPER_TABLE_NAME". If you have another suggestion how to implement it, will be good too! Thanks!

Comment: Usually with joined table inheritance the tables share the same primary key. If the tables are related one-to-one then you shouldn't need to add another (foreign) key just for the purpose of joining them. Have a look for examples of `InheritanceType.JOINED` on the net.

Comment: Hi DuncanKinnear, is everything ok about understand that the primary key will be shared. But when start some container with JPA 2.1 and hibernate as a provider will create an FK_hash in the specific table that reference the ID in the general table. I would like to change this FK_hash name for FK_MY_PREFERED_NAME to work on maintenance in the future. I don't want to add another FK, this FK is created automatically. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.html#foreignKey--) this should do it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANY_SPECIFIC_TABLE_NAME")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "any_specific_any_super_fk"))
public class AnySpecificClass extends AnySuperClass { }
```

It's not easy to find the answer though, with the embedded annotation... it's not obvious where you should be using it.

Not sure this will help you a year later...